# Clojure: pvalues vs. pcalls

Tags: multithreading, clojure, parallel-processing, concurrent-programming

I'm reading [The Joy of Clojure](http://joyofclojure.com), and in the section about paralellization, the functions `pvalues`, `pmap` and `pcalls` are explained, with a brief example of how each one is used. Below are the examples given for `pvalues` and `pcalls`:

```
(defn sleeper [s thing] (Thread/sleep (* 1000 s)) thing)

(pvalues
  (sleeper 2 :1st)
  (sleeper 3 :2nd)
  (keyword "3rd"))

(pcalls
  #(sleeper 2 :1st)
  #(sleeper 3 :2nd)
  #(keyword "3rd"))
```

I understand the technical difference between the two -- `pvalues` takes a variable number of "values" to be computed, whereas `pcalls` takes "an arbitrary number of functions taking no arguments," to be called in parallel. In both cases, a lazy sequence of the results is returned.

My question is essentially, when would you use one vs. the other? It seems like the only semantic difference is that you stick a `#` before each argument to `pcalls`, turning it into an anonymous function. So, purely from the perspective of saving keystrokes and having simpler code, wouldn't it make more sense to just use `pvalues`? -- and if so, why even have a `pcalls` function?

I get that with `pcalls`, you can substitute a symbol referring to a function, but if you wanted to use such a function with `pvalues`, you could just put the function in parentheses so that it is called.

I'm just a little confused as to why Clojure has these 2 functions that are so similar. Is there anything that you can do with one, but not the other? Some contrived examples might be helpful.

Comment: Well pvalues is a macro around pcalls...https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pvalues is a convienience macro around pcalls, though because **macros are not first class** it can't be composed or passed around in the same way a function can. Here is an example where only pcalls works:

```
user> (defn sleeper [s thing] (Thread/sleep (* 1000 s)) thing)
#'user/sleeper

user> (def actions [#(sleeper 2 :1st) #(sleeper 3 :2nd) #(keyword "3rd")])
#'user/actions

user> (apply pcalls actions)
(:1st :2nd :3rd)

user> (apply pvalues actions)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/pvalues, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

It's important when designing APIs in clojure that you don't restrict the users to only  interacting with your library through macros because then they get caught on limitations such as this.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thank you! I had no idea pcalls was a macro (props to RedDeckWins for also pointing that out, and for pointing to the source), but more importantly, I didn't know that macros are not first class! It makes sense when you think about it, I'd just never thought about it :)